# Get Device IP address from firebase console

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am working on a swift application, I am using firebase here. In my firebase console, in the dashboard, I can see the user location, Devices, Demographics, and interests. Are there any options to see the device's IP address? Can anyone help me?[image]

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are not exposed in any of the Analytics reports in the Firebase dashboard. As far as I can see, it is also not present in the [data that can be exported to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en).

So if you need the IP address, you can set it as a user property yourself and then use that either in the dashboard or (more likely) in the BigQuery export of the data.